# Official/Accurate database of Time Zones by city/state or zip or phone

Tags: database, timezone

USPS does not have on official listing of Time Zones by Zip Code. They have up to date street names, 2006/7 lat/lng and up to date city/states.

Also, AT&T (phone) does not have any time zone data from phone area codes (at least they said they don't)

I am looking for the most accurate way to get time zones by either zip code, city or phone number. Whatever is more likely to be accurate. I can make sure the results are not drastically off by looking at the state., but that could still be an hour off.

The focus here is accuracy. What is the most reliable way and/or most trusted source(s). Any help would be appreciated. If it costs something, then that is OK. Don't withhold the suggestion, especially if you think you can speak to its accuracy.

The concern about Phone Number is that some people use out of state area codes from VoIP services. But if that is the most up to date way, we might just use it anyway.

Comment: I have now completed posting [a similar question there](http://getthedata.org/questions/579/officialaccurate-database-of-time-zones-by-citystate-or-zip-or-phone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started with states, had a co-worker come up with the zip codes that were not in the biggest TZ for their state. I don't know how he did it but it was a manual process.

For fun, look up [Time In Indiana on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Indiana). It is a joke-looking history.

GeoNames looks good for an API. Get lat/lng from zip and then TZ

Comment: Indiana is an anvil that's broken a lot of hammers, the exception that tests a lot of rules.

Answer (score 0):

A friend used this for an opensource project: http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm - he had no complaints about its accuracy, but that is hearsay...

Answer (score 0):

ZIP Codes are more accurate and that is becoming truer by the day as more people are keeping cell numbers when they relocate to different areas of the country and - as you mentioned- VoIP usage is increasing. Obviously, good data will accurately reflect daylight savings (including a few areas like Arizona that do not observe it -hard to believe, but true). There is a lot of helpful information here [greatdata.com](http://greatdata.com) including a free lookup tool where you can enter a ZIP Code or Area Code and get the time zone (plus a lot more). Here is the commercial data for your situation [Area Code Database by ZIP Code](http://greatdata.com/area-codes-by-zip-code)

Answer (score 0):

Chronomouse.js is a library that helps you get the current time, GMT offset, time zone name, location, capital city, daylight savings laws, or daylight savings status for any US/Canada area code, or any country code (essentially, from any phone number).

For example:

```
console.log ( getLocalInfo('212',{zone_display: 'area'}).time.zone );

// EST
```

More documentation and examples are available at [www.chronomouse.com](http://www.chronomouse.com)

Note: I am the author of this library.